# PHP PDO & Large Objects (LOB) broken after update

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

A few months ago, my Ubuntu package auto-updated PHP from 7.0.8 to 7.0.13, at which point my script for updating photos stored on a SQL database started failing. I got around this by reinstalling 7.0.8. Last month, I was again auto-updated to 7.0.15 and my script failed again.

My script writes a jpg image to a MS-SQL database, using PDO & FreeTDS, plus Large Objects (LOB) to handle the photo. I emphasise that it worked up to PHP version 7.0.8. The following is a test script isolating my problem.

```
<?php

$dsn = 'dblib:dbname=photos;host=gary';
$id = 693925;

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {    
       $photo = file_get_contents("coco.jpg");
       $query = "UPDATE photo_table SET photo = :photo WHERE id = :id";
       $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
       $stmt->bindValue(":photo", $photo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
       $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->execute();
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The result is an "Incorrect syntax" error!?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 
102 Incorrect syntax near '����'.[102] (severity 15) [(null)]
```

Using the latest available PHP version 7.0.15, reading from the database works, including reading the photo as a Large Object. There is no problem writing every other field to the database, it only fails on my image.

Despite searching over the last few weeks, I still have to find someone else reporting the same problem.

I am after any advice, either a change to the code, or some configuration settings to allow LOBs to work again.

Comment: I would be interested to know if anyone has been successful using LOBs to write to a MS-SQL database with the later versions of PHP.

Comment: This is the prime suspect for the breaking change which went into version 7.0.12    https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72414    There is also a relevant open bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution/workaround was to convert the binary from the image into hexadecimal representation before sending the data to SQL.

```
$photo = bin2hex(file_get_contents("coco.jpg"));
```

converting it back again during the SQL statement.

```
$query = 
"UPDATE photo_table SET photo=CONVERT(varbinary(max), :photo, 2) WHERE id = :id";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **`bindParam`** instead of **`bindValue`** always because in **`bindParam`**

> Unlike [PDOStatement::bindValue()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), the variable is bound as a
> reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
> [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is called.

```
   $photo = file_get_contents("coco.jpg");//change this to below
   $photo = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

   $query = "UPDATE photo_table SET photo = :photo WHERE id = :id";
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

   $stmt->bindValue(":photo", $photo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);//change to this below
   $stmt->bindParam(":photo", $photo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

   $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);//change this to below
   $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This is just only suggestions check here...... http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php & http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-description

Comment: Same result with bindParam :(